# Groovy LinkedHashMap returned from a Jenkins shared library is converted to String

Tags: function, jenkins, groovy, hashmap, return-value

I have a function in a Jenkins shared library which builds and returns a map object (`class java.util.LinkedHashMap`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def call(Map config) {
    script {
        echo "Building nested map"

        def MAP_VAR = [:]

        MAP_VAR.put("one", [:])
        MAP_VAR.put("two", [:])

        MAP_VAR.get("one").put("a", "b")
        MAP_VAR.get("two").put("c", "d")

        echo "Returning: ${MAP_VAR}"
        echo "Type: ${MAP_VAR.getClass()}"

        return MAP_VAR
    }
}
```

When this function runs the log output shows:

```
Returning: [one:[a:b], two:[c:d]]
Type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

But when I call the function and assign the return value to a variable, it ends up being a string (`class java.lang.String`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

library identifier: 'library@main',
        changelog: false,
        retriever: modernSCM([ $class: 'GitSCMSource',
                               remote: 'git@github.com:org/repo.git',
                               credentialsId: 'credentials' ])

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Get map') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Check map') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Value: ${env.MAP_VAR}"
                    echo "Type: ${env.MAP_VAR.getClass()}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output shows:

```
Value: {one={a=b}, two={c=d}}
Type: class java.lang.String
```

Ultimately I'm trying to access the map's properties in multiple stages within the Jenkinsfile. If I try this:

```
echo "Value: ${env.MAP_VAR['one']}"
```

I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: one for class: java.lang.String
```

I've tried:

```
def env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()
```

But that results in:

```
WorkflowScript: 59: unexpected token: def @ line 59, column 21.
                       def env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()
                       ^
```

I've also tried:

```
def Map env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()
```

But that results in:

```
WorkflowScript: 60: unexpected token: Map @ line 60, column 25.
                       def Map env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()
                           ^
```

How can I get the Map/LinkedHashMap from the function as a Map/LinkedHashMap (which would allow me to access the properties/values of the map contents) and assign it to a global variable which can be used in all stages?

Comment: Env could hold only strings. Each time you assign anything to Env - it's automatically converted to string.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Now I will try to find a way to parse a string like `{one={a=b}, two={c=d}}` back into a map.

Answer (score 1):

> def env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()

This will not work as you are trying to define a key `MAP_VAR` in `env` map.

> def Map env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()

This also will not work as you are trying to define `MAP_VAR` key in `env` map as `def` and also `MAP`. This is similar to doing something like `String Integer my_var_name = something()`

> env.MAP_VAR = getMapVar()

You are storing the return value as a string in `env` environment variable map. Jenkins output is accurate given the code.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you can store it as a variable and it will work fine. In the following example, the variable goes into Groovy's script binding and will be available in the next stage. You can also define `def MAP_VAR` outside the pipeline block to get the same result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

library identifier: 'library@main',
        changelog: false,
        retriever: modernSCM([ $class: 'GitSCMSource',
                               remote: 'git@github.com:org/repo.git',
                               credentialsId: 'credentials' ])

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Get map') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    MAP_VAR = getMapVar()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Check map') {
            agent any
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Value: ${MAP_VAR}"
                    echo "Type: ${MAP_VAR.getClass()}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will print

```
Value: [one:[a:b], two:[c:d]]
Type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

In stage two,

```
echo "${MAP_VAR['one']}"
```

will output

```
[a:b]
```